# Assigning Name Of Value To Button Name

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am looking to take the value of one of the buttons in a list. When the user clicks it the button below should display the name of the selected button. I am using AngularJS and I am using the framework Angular Material and that is where the "md-" values are from.

Every time I try to write a function that would capture the value I get stumped and I am completely unsure how to make it logical to bind that data and feed it.

The idea is that the button will capture the name of the above buttons and run a different action depending on the button selected.

```
<md-menu>
        <md-menu-content>
          <md-menu-item>
            <md-button value="Group" ng-click="captureValue()"><p>Group</p></md-button>
          </md-menu-item>

          <md-menu-item>
            <md-button value="Merge" ng-click="captureValue()"><p>Merge</p></md-button>
          </md-menu-item>

          <md-menu-item>
            <md-button value="Hide" ng-click="captureValue()"><p>Hide</p></md-button>
          </md-menu-item>

        </md-menu-content>
</md-menu>

<!-- This button should display the name of one of the buttons above -->
<md-button>{{ Value of the selected button above should go here"</mdbutton>
```

Comment: provide your controller as well

Answer (score 0):

You can pass something (for example, the button text) into your `captureValue` function:

```
<md-menu-item>
  <md-button ng-click="captureValue('Group')"><p>Group</p></md-button>
</md-menu-item>

<md-menu-item>
  <md-button ng-click="captureValue('Merge')"><p>Merge</p></md-button>
</md-menu-item>

<md-menu-item>
  <md-button ng-click="captureValue('Hide')"><p>Hide</p></md-button>
</md-menu-item>
```

Then `captureValue` can use it in some way:

```
function captureValue(text) {
  this.lastClickedButtonText = text;
}
```

Display it:

```
<md-button>{{ ctrlName.lastClickedButtonText }}</mdbutton>
```

---

This all assumes you're using the controller bind method, rather than the `$scope` method.

If you're using `$scope` it's not all that different:

```
$scope.captureValue = function(text) {
  $scope.lastClickedButtonText = text;
}
```

And display it:

```
<md-button>{{ lastClickedButtonText }}</mdbutton>
```

---

Or, if you'd like to be more direct and `captureValue` has no additional logic to run you can keep it all in the view, as the body of an `ng-click` can be almost any single JS statement.

```
<md-button ng-click="lastClickedButtonText = 'Group'"><p>Group</p></md-button>
```

I realise in practice you're unlikely to only want to capture the value of the button, this is just an example to show you can use almost any JS statement in angular directives like `ng-click`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-click="captureValue(this);"

"this" as a parameter will give to your function (captureValue) the element that as been clicked. Then get what you have to get and do what you have to do.